# C++20 Pass Familiar Template lambda as Class Template to Template Parameter of a Class

Tags: c++, lambda, c++20, template-templates, class-template

Consider passing a callable class template as a template parameter to some class. Three approaches as below but only functor one works.

The naive template function failed because it cannot serve as a class template; However, why the C++20 familiar template lambda fails? https://godbolt.org/z/MaYdqx1do

```cpp
template <typename T>
T SomeFunc() {
    return T{};
}

template <typename T>
struct SomeFunctor {
    T operator()() const { return T{}; }
};

auto SomeLambda = []<typename T>() { return T{}; };

template <template <typename> class F>
struct Foo {
    int operator()() const { return F<int>()(); }
};

int some_func_result = Foo<decltype(&SomeFunc)>()(); // cannot compile
int some_functor_result = Foo<SomeFunctor>()();
int some_lambda_result = Foo<decltype(SomeLambda)>()(); // cannot compile
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer my own question. Familiar template lambdas(introduced in c++ 20) are like anonymous functors(function object) but templated on the operator instead of on the class. It essentially translates to below functor class in theory. Therefore there's no way for the user class to apply it as a class template for its template argument. https://godbolt.org/z/1TddKan6n

```cpp
auto SomeLambda = []<typename T>() { return T{}; };

struct SomeLambdaGut {
    template <typename T>
    T operator()() const { return T{}; }
};
```